# Read all the data in one go of all the folders and store in a single dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I need data in a Dataframe in one go after India but only the data from the Processed_Parquet(some more folders are there inside the Categories, but I only need Processed_Parquet) folder.

Path : `"/mnt/adls/Centrallake/ExternalSources/Nilesh/BlobFileShare/India/**Categories**/Processed_Parquet"`

Where Categories are :

1. Books
2. Pen
3. Pencil
4. Bag
5. Notebooks

I want data in a single Dataframe of all the categories **without using Union or Join** because in the future folders inside the categories can be increased and decreased.

I am thinking of trying for a loop on top of the above-mentioned path, but how to do this? I'm totally new to Azure databricks and scala.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced above and able to read the files like below.

This is my Folder Structure like above.

[image]

Inisde all folders I have same structure like this. I have used `.csv` files for my repro. You can use `.parquet` while reading.

```
BlobFileShare/India/**Categories**/Processed_Parquet
```

I did like this in Scala and got the desired dataframe.

```
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes
import java.nio.file._
import scala.collection.mutable.MutableList

import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

val files = ArrayBuffer.empty[Path]

val root = Paths.get("/dbfs/mnt/mount1/")

//reads all .csv files in the mount1 path recursively
Files.walkFileTree(root, new SimpleFileVisitor[Path] {
  override def visitFile(file: Path, attrs: BasicFileAttributes) = {
    if (file.getFileName.toString.endsWith(".csv")) {
      files += file
    }
    FileVisitResult.CONTINUE
  }
})

// coneverting to string list
val l=files.toList
val s_list=l.map(_.toString)

// filtering Processed_Parquet folder name in the path
val temp_list=s_list.filter(_ contains("Processed_Parquet"))

// Getting list of files with starting like /mnt/path
val final_list= MutableList[String]()
for(x <- temp_list){
  final_list+=x.slice(6,x.length)
}

// Read the files with file path list
val df=spark.read.option("header",true).csv(final_list: _*)
df.show()
```

**Execution:**

[image]

Comment: Getting error like : NoSuchFileException: "path" 
Mount Point have more files inside it and all files are having data.

Comment: Make sure that you are giving correct file path starting with `/dbfs/mnt/path`.

Comment: PATH : /dbfs/mnt/adls/Centrallake/ExternalSources/Nilesh/BlobFileShare/India/          I am giving the corrct path only

Comment: Try like this `/dbfs/mnt/<your mount point>/your ADLS  path from folder`.

Comment: import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes
import java.nio.file._
import scala.collection.mutable.MutableList

import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

val files = ArrayBuffer.empty[Path]

val root = Paths.get("dbfs/mnt/adls/Centrallake/ExternalSources/Nilesh/BlobFileShare/India/*/Processed_Parquet/")

Comment: //reads all .parquet files in the centrallake path recursively
Files.walkFileTree(root, new SimpleFileVisitor[Path] {
  override def visitFile(file: Path, attrs: BasicFileAttributes) = {
    if (file.getFileName.toString.endsWith(".parquet")) {
      files += file
    }
    FileVisitResult.CONTINUE
  }
})

Comment: // coneverting to string list
val l=files.toList
val s_list=l.map(_.toString)

// filtering Processed_Parquet folder name in the path
val temp_list=s_list.filter(_ contains("Processed_Parquet"))

// Getting list of files with starting like /mnt/path
val final_list= MutableList[String]()
for(x <- temp_list){
  final_list+=x.slice(6,x.length)
}

// Read the files with file path list
val df=spark.read.option("header",true).csv(final_list: _*)
df.head(1)

Comment: These are the above codes I'm trying

Comment: Don't give wild card in the path give like `/dbfs/mnt/adls/Centrallake/ExternalSources/Nilesh/BlobFileShare/India/` or only till `/dbfs/mnt/`.

Comment: Still getting the same error. Tried both /dbfs/mnt/adls/Centrallake/ExternalSources/Nilesh/BlobFileShare/India/ and /dbfs/mnt/ I am giving the path and mount point correct, don't know why we are getting this error.